# How to work out the speed lost by a bike while jumping through the air by air resistance

Tags: calculus

I am trying to work out much speed is lost while a mountain bike is jumping though the air and ultimately how much distance they will loose because of this.

I have calculated the force generated by air resistance using the force equation. 0.5*v^2*CrossSectionalArea*Airpressure*DragCoeffcient = f and have calculated 
the total distance the bike travelled and the time it took.

For example, the rider hits a 42 degree jump at 20 m/s, he travels 40.6 meters(with no air resistance) in 2.73 seconds with an initial velocity of 13.38  m/s and a final velocity of 14.86 m/s and the force generated by air resistance is 110.3 newtons what is the reduction in distance due to the force created by air resistance?

Thank you :)

Comment: Is this really a mathematics problem?  There's numbers and formulas in it, but it seems like the real issue is the physical accuracy or adequacy of your model.

Comment: I understand that the model is very basic but this is just for my computer science A level project, it does not need to be completely accurate, I am just trying to understand the basic maths behind this :)